# Why !important is not working in react js with inline style

Tags: reactjs

I am using inline style in react js like

```
style={{ textAlign: "center !important;" }}
```

Answer (score 4):

As it is not possible in reactJs, please read this article https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1881#issuecomment-262257503

But there is a way you can still use it :

```
<div ref={element => { 
         if (element) element.style.setProperty('textAlign', 'center', 'important'); 
       }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this:

```
<div ref={(node) => {
    if (node) {
        node.style.setProperty("float", "right", "important");
    }
}}>
                
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with setting className prop

Answer (score 0):

In case you're using inline CSS because you want it dependent on a variable:

```
// IN CSS file
.forceOpacity {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

// IN Component
const [isShown, setIsShown] = useState(false)

return(
<div className={isShown ? "forceOpacity" : ""}></div>
)
```

Answer (score -2):

try simple without "!important;"

```
style={{ textAlign: "center" }}
```

Comment: He wants important to work but giving this answer is not asked by question

Comment: This is essentially the same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67265885/19068). It doesn't work for the same reason and it's a pretty pointless duplicate of something that has already been said as well.

Comment: sometimes it's important to have `!important`